# Did I lose my GPG data?

Tags: backup, encryption, gnupg

I copied my GPG data from another computer by just copying `~/.gnupg/*` to an external drive.

I can't quite figure out where this leaves me. I'd read that this works, but can't figure out how to get it set up again. GPG won't list any keys.

I didn't do `--export` and `--import` because I figured this saved me a couple steps (and, again, had read that it would work).

Answer (score 1):

GnuPG does not scan all your drives and folders for its home directory, but looks for it as dedicated places, by default only `~/.gnupg` (in other words, in your home directory).

If you want to use it on another computer, use the `--homedir` option, for example `gpg --homedir=/media/usb/.gnupg --list-keys`. If you copied your GnuPG home directory back on another computer, you might have to take ownership again using `chown $USER:$USER ~/.gnupg`, as even when using the same user name, the underlying numeric IDs might have changed. Also, if you only copied the GnuPG home directory's contents (`~/.gnupg/*` does that), you'll have to apply proper permissions (`chmod 700 ~/.gnupg`) to the enclosing directory, GnuPG is rather picky on others being able to read your files.

Comment: Did all of that. I took a screenshot of my actions and the apparent results. http://i.imgur.com/nxkQRj5.png

Comment: Both your public and secret keyring are empty (look at the file size). Are they also empty on your thumb drive?

Comment: Yes, yes they are.

It's lost.